# What's the advantage of applying settings with NEFilterDataProvider.apply(_:) over manually checking incoming network flows?

Tags: cocoa, networkextension

I cannot find in the documentation if using `[NEFilterDataProvider.apply(_:)][1]` has any advantage over manually inspecting incoming flows in `handleNewFlow(_:)` other than being a shortcut. Or are those rules guaranteed to be applied even if the network extension crashes or similar? If it has no practical advantages, then manually inspecting each flow allows to set up more flexible dynamic rules.